# Why is there an extra space in the output of this function?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I haven't been able to figure out why when I run this code in replit, it returns an extra space between the answer and undefined. The '\n' has to be there for it to be formatted the way it is but can anyone explain how to get rid of the space? Appreciate any help.

Code:

```js
function transposeTwoStrings(array) {
  var x = array[0];
  var y = array[1];
  var longestString = 0;
  var result = '';

  if(x.length > y.length) {
    longestString = x;
  }
  else if(y.length > x.length) {
    longestString = y;
  }
  else if(x.length === y.length) {
    longestString = x;
  }
  
  for(var i = 0; i < longestString.length; i++) {
    result += ((x[i] || ' ') + ' ' +(y[i] || ' ')) + '\n';
  }             
  return result;
} 
   
console.log(transposeTwoStrings(['Hello','World']));
```

```
      Replit Output:

      H W
      e o
      l r
      l l
      o d
                         <--(This is the space)
      => undefined
```

Comment: I get no space when running this in the console but undefined always seems to appear when running function in via copy/paste. If you swap the `console.log()` for `alert()` you will see your function has no problems or false returns.

Comment: repl.it just adds a newline after every console.log

Comment: I can't replicate this either but you do have a trailing `\n` after the last `d` which you could remove with the `trim()` function.

Comment: It is probably just the console you are using. It doesn't appear in a Chrome browser.

Comment: Yeah, I don't get a space in the console but I do in replit. It's actually a codewars exercise and it's saying that there's an extra space as well. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You get a newline `\n` at the end which is ignored by some browsers. You can remove it with `trim()`

```
function transposeTwoStrings(array) {
    var x = array[0];
    var y = array[1];
    var longestString = 0;
    var result = '';

    if (x.length > y.length) {
        longestString = x;
    }

    else if (y.length > x.length) {
        longestString = y;
    }

    else if (x.length === y.length) {
        longestString = x;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < longestString.length; i++) {
        result += ((x[i] || ' ') + ' ' + (y[i] || ' ')) + '\n';
    }
    return result.trim();
}
console.log(transposeTwoStrings(['Hello', 'World']));
```

Comment: Why not just `return result.trim()`?

Answer (score 0):

You could modify your `for` loop to only add a newline to all but the last line, instead of `+ '\n'` after each:

```
for (var i = 0; i < longestString.length; i++) {
    result += ((x[i] || ' ') + ' ' + (y[i] || ' '));
    if(i < longestString.length - 1) {result += '\n';}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you help!